# Remove games from origin list

Tags: origin

I've spent the last couple of days engrossed in Battlefield 3. However I also took part in the Alpha and the Beta testing, so in my Origin account, I have multiple entries for BF3 (one for alpha, one for beta, one for retail).

Obviously, I can't play the old 2 anymore, so does anyone know of a way to remove these from the Origin game list? There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a way to actually remove the game from Origin, but there is a way to hide the game from actually appearing in Origin. Open the file

`C:\ProgramData\Origin\InstalledGames.xml`

The Battlefield Beta has an ID of 71171. Find that line and change

`hidden="0"` to  `hidden="1"`

I'm not quite sure what the ID for the alpha is, but you could just follow a similar process to remove that one as well.

Comment: This no longer works. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Tr0n, you could try grouping the unwanted entries and then collapse the group, or at least you can do so in Steam. Don't know about Origin.

Answer (score 3):

You need to contact EA support. They will disable whichever games you want.

Comment: They? You mean YOU..

Answer (score 3):

Note that in order to remove a game from your EA Origin account you MUST call the phone support.

It does NOT work if you contact them via email, web form or online chat - they will either do nothing at all or they will tell you to contact the phone support. It is only possible by directly speaking to a person!

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked 2011, but in 2017 people will still stumble upon it.

Meanwhile, contacting EA support is no longer required to remove a game from Origin.
Right-click the game in Origin and select "Hide". This will hide the game in your library. If you want to see it later again, you have to open the "Filter" menu and enable showing hidden games.